# Burning formaldehyde gas for disposal?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Since formaldehyde gas is flammable, is there a safe way to burn it, and can this be done to dispose of the gas or neutralize its harmful effects (tear production, respiratory problems, etc.)?

This is a more detailed form of my earlier question, including the context of "gas disposal".